# Meaning and use of two sentences

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the following sentences:

1. What answer would that be ? (Is it imagining or asking or what? What's the possible meaning and use of this sentence?)
2. He is a farmer but it wouldn't mean that he's laborious. (why "wouldn't" has been used here instead of using "doesn't"  meaning here?)

While reading through articles in internet i've found those two sentences. But, I can't say where they were exactly.

I would appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What answer would that be?**

The most likely interpretation I can think of for this question is that it is asking somebody to provide context for an answer that they have just mentioned. As in:

*Fred: "I have the answer!"*

*Mary: "What answer would that be?"*

*Fred: "Oh, I just figured out [something]."*

In my example, at first Mary doesn't know what Fred is talking about because he has just blurted out that he has "the answer" without explaining what question it answers, so Mary asks him what answer he is talking about.

(There may be other interpretations. If you could quote the sentences that appeared before that one then perhaps I could help further.)

> **He is a farmer but it wouldn't mean that he's laborious.** *(why "wouldn't" has been used here and what's its meaning here?)*

When describing a person, [laborious](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/laborious?s=t) means "diligent and hard-working". Farmers are often thought of as being very hard-working, getting up early and spending the day doing physically demanding tasks out in the fields. Your sentence seems to be saying that although "he" is a farmer, that doesn't necessarily mean that he actually does work hard.

It's kind of an odd way to phrase it though. I would use *that* rather than *it* and *doesn't* rather than *wouldn't*: "He is a farmer, but that doesn't mean that he's laborious."

In general, the form *he is X, but that doesn't mean he is Y* is saying that although people who are X are often Y too, they don't *have* to be.

Comment: is it wrong to use "wouldn't' ? Why wouldn't has been used instead of doesn't ?

Comment: Does the first sentence implys the imagination of the speaker about the answer ?

Comment: To *me* the first sentence does *not* imply that the speaker is imagining anything about the answer, I think it is a straightforward request for clarification about an answer that somebody else has mentioned. In the second sentence, I don't know if it is strictly wrong to use "wouldn't", but it sounds odd to me. I can't say why it was used in this case - perhaps I could make more sense of it if you had quoted the sentences that came before it. That use of "laborious" sounds a little odd to me too - although it's not incorrect it's not the adjective I would choose there.

Comment: ok,do you mean mary is asking fred "what is the answer ?"or  "what that answer of ?  " what that Answer of ?"  with politely?

Comment: In my own example with Fred and Mary, Fred has mentioned that he has the answer when Mary didn't even know there was a question. She didn't know what he was talking about, and "What answer would that be?" was her way of asking what he was talking about. She would expect him to explain both what the question was and what his answer is.

Comment: P.S. Note that of course the whole Fred/Mary thing was a scenario that I made up to give an example where the sentence "What answer would that be?" would actually make sense. It's possible it meant something else in the context where you saw it, but taken out of context I interpret it in the way I've explained.

Comment: i got it what you mean. But, i would think mary is asking Fred indirectly and hypothetically because the word 'would' has been used here. So, she is just showing that she's unware or unknown about answer of which question. Her asking question looks as if she is talking to herself rather than making a polite request to Fred. I would think Her question is somewhat imaginative, monologues, indirect. Because she wants him to further explain what his answer/question about. Am i right ?

What would you think of my openion in your example?

Comment: In *my* example Mary is talking directly to Fred. In another context somebody asking that question might be talking to themselves and imagining any number of hypothetical things, but taken out of context as in your original post we have no way of knowing what prompted the question or whether the speaker was talking to themselves, another person, or a group.

Comment: Could you please also tell  me about other context where there this question or phrase could be better fitted?

Comment: I can't think of a context where it would be *better* fitted. But another context might be if you were reading articles online and you saw a headline "We finally have the answer". You might say to yourself, "And what answer would that be?"

Comment: Umm ,That's the context I was looking for. It means monologues.Isn't it ?

Comment: I think it's monologues raher than a real question.

Comment: And ,  What do you think of second sentene , in which context i would be better fitted ?